# Exactly How and Where Does The Trending Posts System Work Inside A Server?

Tags: database, mongodb, algorithm, web, azure-sql-database

I know this question is fairly simple for you and there are many related answers but none of them explain all what I need.

So you all must have been to YouTube, there you must have seen the Trending Posts Section, where all the videos which have the most views/likes/dislikes (I don't know exactly) w.r.t the time are listed. Now, all those videos are from different different channels.

I want to know:

1. There must be an algorithm or function inside the server to do that? If there is one, then when do it runs, i.e, are the results kept ready inside the server the same a google search engine --- which keeps the pages stored according to their ranking and whenever someone searches it delivers the result.
2. The above algorithm goes through every posts, right? But when? How does it knows that this post from this youtuber is getting this amount of views or a lot of views.
3. Now, after it knows which posts are trending --- where are they stored. Like, if we take mongodb database. Is it kept in a different collection like trending posts or their id's

I know the above questions must be confusing because of my half(or no) knowledge. But, please help me know it all. I am trying to get this answer for a very long time. Any guides or tutorials appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The system needs to *store* each view/like including a timestamp. Using this it can find highest counts for the latest period

Comment: Now, if I store views and likes with timestamp for each post. Then the function which is going to decide their ranking in the server would run when? I mean all the time in or how? Please elaborate in details, I'm really confused.

Comment: There is no reason to store likes and timestamps.  Generate stats in realtime using a leaky buckets algorithm.  Each like coming in adds to level, which leaks down over time. Buckets that over flow are trending.  This is just a simple counter on each video.

Answer (score 2):

For a "trending posts" feature you would have to store **each view/like/etc** (whatever you consider as a metric for "popular"). You also need to store a **timestamp**, so that you can select for "current popularity" as opposed to "in the past". And maybe store some **identity** of the viewer, so that each visitor is only counted once.

Next you have to find out which post is trending at the moment. For this you would need to find out the posts with the highest number of views in the past timespan. It is up to you (and the nature of the system you are running) whether you use hours, days, weeks or even months.

This query is probably too expensive to run on each pageview, plus the results don't change that much from minute to minute. So you would run this on some schedule, for instance once every hour. Again, it is up to you decide how accurate you want/need it. Maybe run this several times an hour, or just once a day. You do need to store the list of "trending posts" somewhere, so you can display it easily.